# How do I put the results of a MySQL query with matching column value into associative array based on that value with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a database with a vertical schema, explained:

Key, Cat, UID, Var, Val, etc...
Where Key is the index, Cat is the category, UID is the identifier for a group of rows, var is the name of the value the row represents and Val is that value.  So a few rows would look something like this:

```
key cat   uid    var          val
 1   1   98765  name         David
 2   1   98765  description  handsome, young, sporting, 
 3   1   98765  phone        123-456-789
 4   1   98765  email        david@handsome.com
 5   1   12345  name         Jason
 6   1   12345  description  cool, hot, tall, 
 7   1   12345  phone        222-555-1244
 8   1   12345  email        jason@cool.org
 8   1   12345  website      www.jason.com
```

So the goal with the query/php is to get all rows from a specified category, then return an associative array based on the uid for all the rows with that uid.  The result would be somehting like

```
results{
["98765"] => ["name"] = David
          => ["description"] = handsome, young, sporting,
          => ["phone"] = 123-456-789
          => ["email"] = david@handsome.com
["12345"] => ["name"] = Jason
          => ["description"] = cool, hot, tall,
          => ["phone"] = 222-555-1244
          => ["email"] = jason@cool.org
          => ["website"] = www.jason.com
}
```

Hopefully that's understandable, let me know if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$category = 1;
$result = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat = ' . intval( $category));
$results = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result))
{
    $results[ $row['uid'] ][ $row['var'] ] = $row['val'];
}
mysql_free_result( $result);
```

Comment: That worked very well, thank you.  Is this the most efficient way to accomplish this?  Or would using something like fetchAll() be better?

Comment: You'd need MySQLi to use `fetch_all()`, and the efficiency difference is likely insignificant, as you will still need to iterate over the entire result set to form your array correctly.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Don't forget to vote / accept an answer to your questions - [The FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) will help you if you're unfamiliar with stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

if the reason for doing this is to access the results using result["98765"] type syntax you may be better using objects. you could reference the objects or use an array of objects but the code would look a lot cleaner

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? Seems more suited for a comment if anything.

Comment: i was merly giving an alternative solution that may help him achieve a similar result.the other comment gives an exact solution to achieve what he requires in his current question

Comment: It is, and it isn't.  I want to output the array via json, and it's easier to parse when the associative array is formatted like this.  I'm definitely open to suggestions though, can you provide an example?